# Code displays contents of a directory on the console but it doesn't wait for `getch()`

Tags: c++, windows, dirent.h

When I use the first lot of code there is no error, however when I use the second lot of code the program runs and display contents of a directory on the console but it doesn't wait for `getch()` and Windows say that the program has stopped working.

First lot of code (works):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dirent.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    DIR *dir=NULL;
    struct dirent *sdir;

    dir= opendir(".");

    while(sdir=readdir(dir)){

        cout<<endl<<sdir->d_name;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Second lot of code (stops working):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dirent.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    DIR *dir=NULL;
    struct dirent *sdir;

    dir= opendir(".");
    sdir=readdir(dir); cout<<sdir->d_name;
    while(sdir){
        sdir=readdir(dir);
        cout<<endl<<sdir->d_name;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fix your question first for us to understand what you have done so far.

Comment: When you define the pointer variable `sdir`, where does it initially point? Also take some time to read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: In the first case you test the result of `readdir` before using it. In the second case you test the result *after* using it. You also have an uninitialized pointer the first time in `while (sdir)`.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the program runs correctly but stops working"_? This is somewhat contradictory. And also explain what you mean exactly by _"stops working"_, is there some error message displayed?

Comment: the program runs and display contents of directory on console but it doesn't wait for getch() and windows say that the program has stopped working.

Comment: Besides my initial point (where does `sdir` point if you don't initialize it) where does `sdir` point when you have iterated over the whole directory and `readdir` returns `NULL`?

Comment: Iam new to dirent.h please explain in detail.

Comment: I also initialized in this way but still its not working  " sdir = readdir(dir);" before while loop & rest of code is same.                                                                                                 I know that the output will not display the first file but it should run correctly which in my case runs and then windows say the program has stopped working.

Comment: Included comments from OP clarifying problem with code. Update title to also reflect this. Formatted code.